# Sinch Call audio not working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sinch

All the delegate methods of SINCallDelegate are working fine but most of the time audio does not work although client was connected successfully.

Comment: can you call all SINCallDelegate in appdelegate?

Comment: @BijenderSinghShekhawat thanks for you precious reply, Actually it was fixed a long ago, now I am facing an issue that, when User A calls User B, User B disconnect the call after receiving it, than call failed screen of call kit appears at the User A end, I don't want this screen to be displayed as whatsapp also don't show this screen how can i prevent this screen to be displayed?

Comment: I am working on the same issue you can download my app "Domus chat" from the app store.

Comment: @MohammadFarhan I am facing the same issue can you specify your solution here so, It will help us too..

Answer (score 0):

Swift- 5  Very Easy and Simply I am Done

```
//MARK:- ahmedshakeelpk@gmail.com //Contact me i will resolve the issue in 10 min

@UIApplicationMain class AppDelegate: UIResponder, SINClientDelegate, SINCallClientDelegate, SINManagedPushDelegate, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {
    //MARK:- the simple suggestion can handle with PushKit for more details contact me to help you out.
}
```